# Pandas - fill NaN based on the previous value of another cell

Tags: python, pandas

I have some stocks data in a dataframe that I'm resampling, which results in some NaN values. Here's a section of the raw feed:

```
In [34]: feeddf
Out[34]:
                      open   high    low  close  volume
date
2017-12-03 07:00:00  14.46  14.46  14.46  14.46   25000
2017-12-03 07:01:00  14.46  14.46  14.46  14.46   20917
2017-12-03 07:06:00  14.50  14.50  14.50  14.50    2000
2017-12-03 07:12:00  14.50  14.56  14.50  14.56   17000
```

The feed is supposed to be minute-by-minute, but when there's not data available, the row is skipped. When resampling the dataframe and aggregating for the opens, highs, lows, and closes, it looks like this:

```
In [35]: feeddf.resample('3Min').agg({'open': 'first', 
                                      'high': 'max',  
                                      'low': 'min',  
                                      'close': 'last'})
Out[35]:
                      open   high    low  close
date
2017-12-03 07:00:00  14.46  14.46  14.46  14.46
2017-12-03 07:03:00    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
2017-12-03 07:06:00  14.50  14.50  14.50  14.50
2017-12-03 07:09:00    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
2017-12-03 07:12:00  14.50  14.56  14.50  14.56
```

**My question**: I want to forward-fill the missing data based on the last row's `close` value. `df.fillna(method='ffill')` is not helping because it fills it based on the last value on the same column. Any idea?

Comment: Do you think `df.fillna(14.56)` - `df.fillna(df['close'].iat[-1])` ?

Comment: hello again! Can you explain a bit? I don't think I'm getting what you're saying.

Comment: I add comment because not sure if understand - from your sample need replace all NaNs by last value of `close` column - here `14.54` ?

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: I meant the last `close` value of the current row. For example, all `NaN`'s in the second row should be `14.46`, but all `NaN`'s of the 4th row should be `14.50`.

Comment: OK, so why is not possible use `df.fillna(method='ffill')` ?

Comment: The example I have put is kinda bad, because both rows before the `NaN`'s  have the same values. The values are usually different, and I want the `NaN`'s to be filled with the `close` value.

Comment: For example, if there's a row with NaN after the last row, I want the NaN's to be filled with `14.56`, not `14.50`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First forward fill last column `close` and then `bfill` by columns:

```
print (df)
                      open   high    low  close
date                                           
2017-12-03 07:00:00  14.46  14.46  14.46  14.81
2017-12-03 07:03:00    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
2017-12-03 07:06:00  14.50  14.50  14.50  14.59
2017-12-03 07:09:00    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
2017-12-03 07:12:00  14.50  14.56  14.50  14.56


df['close'] = df['close'].ffill()
df = df.bfill(axis=1)
print (df)
                      open   high    low  close
date                                           
2017-12-03 07:00:00  14.46  14.46  14.46  14.81
2017-12-03 07:03:00  14.81  14.81  14.81  14.81
2017-12-03 07:06:00  14.50  14.50  14.50  14.59
2017-12-03 07:09:00  14.59  14.59  14.59  14.59
2017-12-03 07:12:00  14.50  14.56  14.50  14.56
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks again!