# How to fill NaN cells in a pandas dataframe, based on the previous column?

Tags: python, pandas, nan

I have the following DF

```
col1| col2
 123| NaN
 234| 234
 456| NaN
 567| 567
```

and what I want to do, is to copy the left cell to the right cell if the right cell is empty, so the output is

```
col1| col2
 123| 123
 234| 234
 456| 456
 567| 567
```

I tried to work something with fillna, but failed miserably

Comment: @jezrael Check [`this`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48521360/pandas-fill-nan-based-on-the-previous-value-of-another-cell) out. If this looks close to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.where` from the `numpy` package

Assuming your dataframe is called `df`:

```
import numpy as np
df['col2'] = np.where(df['col2'].isnull(),df['col1'],df['col2'])
```

which will give you:

```
col1| col2
 123| 123
 234| 234
 456| 456
 567| 567
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `ffill` by columns, so `axis=1`:

```
df = df.ffill(axis=1)
print (df)
    col1   col2
0  123.0  123.0
1  234.0  234.0
2  456.0  456.0
3  567.0  567.0
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df.fillna(method='ffill',axis=1)
```